# Returning Full URL

Tags: development, master-page

I am writing code in my master page that examines the page's URL as shown in the browser

I have a web application at URL:

```
http://teams.sharepoint.org/sitecollections
```

and many site collections within it like this:

```
http://teams.sharepoint.org/sitecollections/site1
http://teams.sharepoint.org/sitecollections/site2
http://teams.sharepoint.org/sitecollections/site3
```

The code snippet I am using to examine the URL is:

```
Uri uri = Context.Request.Url;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append(" uri.AbsolutePath = " + uri.AbsolutePath + "<br />");
sb.Append("uri.AbsoluteUri = " + uri.AbsoluteUri + "<br />");
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

When I navigate to any of the above site collections the returned path is as expected.

```
Full URL to Page: http://teams.sharepoint.org/sitecollections/site1/Pages/default.aspx

Output of code snippet:
    uri.AbsolutePath = /sitecollections/site1/Pages/default.aspx
    uri.AbsoluteUri = http://teams.sharepoint.org/sitecollections/site1/Pages/default.aspx
```

Now notice what is returned when I navigate to the site settings page for any of the site collections.

The URL to the site settings is:

```
http://teams.sharepoint.org/sitecollections/site1/_layouts/settings.aspx
```

But now the code snippet returns only the /_layouts/settings.aspx portion and does not return the '/sitecollections/site1/' portion of the URL.

```
uri.AbsolutePath = /_layouts/settings.aspx
uri.AbsoluteUri = http://teams.sharepoint.org/_layouts/settings.aspx
```

Why is that omitted?  The omitted portion is the part that I need to examine and act on but it is not returned.

Thanks for reading

Comment: What version of SP are you using?

Comment: 2010 enterprise

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're having the same problem faced here: [Absolute URLs not working with Virtual Directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703459/absolute-urls-not-working-with-virtual-directories)

Try something like this to check if the path contains a SharePoint mapped / virtual directory:

```
Uri uri = Context.Request.Url;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append(" uri.AbsolutePath = " + uri.AbsolutePath + "<br />");

if (uri.AbsolutePath.Substring(0, 2) == "/_")
{
    string absoluteUri = 
      HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) +
      HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath +
      uri.AbsolutePath;
    sb.Append("uri.AbsoluteUri = " + absoluteUri + "<br />");
}
else
{
    sb.Append("uri.AbsoluteUri = " + uri.AbsoluteUri + "<br />");
}

Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Just make sure you test it, because I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint 2010, you can use the SharePoint client object model to return the URL of the Site collection:

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
Site siteCollection = clientContext.Site;

var url = site.Url + "/_layouts/settings.aspx";
```

The MSDN article for the Client OM is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx

Comment: Seems very unnatural to use the client side object model for code that executes server side.  Seems like there should be a server side call that will do what I want.  I appreciate the help though.